# About the RoR Update DB Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql

I would like to use the ruby on rails and mysql to write a simple test program
but, in this time, i can not update the database record.
because i use the "mid" to replaced the "id" column
in this case, what can i do to work to update the record?

**Problem:**

```
Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause': UPDATE `messages` SET `message` = 'ccc', `subject` = 'aaa', `author` = 'bbb' WHERE `id` = NULL
```

**My Code:**

```
def update
    @message = Message.find(:first, :conditions => ["mid = ?", params[:id]])
    if @message.update_attributes(params[:message])
        flash[:notice] = 'Post was successfully updated.'
        redirect_to gbook_path(:id => @message.mid)
    else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    end
end
```

**Database:**

```
CREATE TABLE `demo_development`.`message` (
`mid` MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`subject` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
`author` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
`message` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`adddate` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to tell ActiveRecord that your primary key is not the convention of 'id'.

Use the "set_primary_key" method.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :mid
end
```

Documented here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002290